# React Redux - how to trigger action after another action without Component

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-persist

I'm using [react-persist](https://github.com/rt2zz/redux-persist) to save redux state to local storage.

I want to make an api call based on the persisted state, so I want to dispatch the request call right after the action persist/REHYDRATE (defined by the library and executed on its own) occurs.

Which is the best way to achieve this?

Comment: Do you want something like this? https://stackoverflow.com/a/49540589/7060441

Comment: @devserkan no, I already use redux thunk to make batch request. What I want to do is to trigger an action when occurs the action of a library which is not controlled by me.

Comment: Oh, I see now. Sorry for misleading.

Answer (score 1):

The posted answer has a mistake so I thought of improving the mistaken answer:
According to the question "I want to dispatch the request call right AFTER the action persist/REHYDRATE".

```
import {API_CALL} from "./ACTION/API/index"


let hasRehydrated = false;

const onRehydrationMiddleware = store => next => action => {
    // if this Action happens to be 'persist/REHYDRATE' then follow it up with your 
    // desired Action
    if (!hasRehydrated && action.type === 'persist/REHYDRATE') {
        hasRehydrated = true;
        next(action); // this is to make sure you get the Rehydrated State before making                                 
                      // the store.dispatch(API_CALL()) call
        store.dispatch(API_CALL()); //
    } else {
        // make a call to the next action
        next(action);
    }
};
```

thanks to timotgl for his answer

Answer (score 0):

Try this middleware:

```
let hasRehydrated = false;

const onRehydrationMiddleware = store => next => action => {
    if (!hasRehydrated && action.type === 'persist/REHYDRATE') {
        hasRehydrated = true;
        store.dispatch(callApi());
    } else {
        next(action);
    }
};
```

You might not need to remember wether `persist/REHYDRATE` was already dispatched before (I wasn't sure if it happens only once), in this case just remove the flag. Otherwise it will remember the event in module scope where your middleware lives, which works fine as a poor man's singleton pattern.

The middleware is basically never needed again after this event, but I don't think it's possible to throw them out after creating the store. You could use `store.subscribe(listener)` but the listener doesn't see actions. Another option would be to detect that rehydration happened based on the state, which I'm assuming changes in some way. Then store.subscribe would work, and you could call the api and unsubscribe right after.